# How to initialize Neo4j driver on Django

Tags: python, django, neo4j, graph-databases

I use Neo4j as an external database for additional requests in my Django project. There is an issue that I got stuck on, where should I initialize the Neo4j driver in my Django project? I do not want to recreate and close neo4j driver every time that requests came. So currently, I edited my settings.py file, I imported neo4j GraphDatabase and I initialized Neo4j driver as I mentioned below.

```
..settings.py

from neo4j import GraphDatabase

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("neo4j://localhost:7687", auth=("test", "test"))
```

But the problem is that I don't know if settings.py file the proper place to initialize Neo4j driver. Where should I initialize global variables in my Django project? Can you help me about this, please?

Thanks.